# Why do I keep getting the same outputs?

Tags: python

I am creating a for loop and I keep getting the output twice:

```
totalelements = len(uniquevalueslist)

for id in [23, 45, 76]:
    if id not in uniquevaluelist:
        stmt = f"""INSERT INTO..."""
        for x in range(totalelements):
            stmt = stmt + f" SELECT...."
            if x < totalelements-1:
                stmt = stmt + "UNION ALL "
            else:
                stmt += stmt
```

My output is that I get the INSERT INTO Statement Twice

Comment: uniquevaluelist should be with an `s`. also, you might have forgot to define the var.

Answer (score 0):

the `if` statement is inside the `for` loop. this means it will be evaluated each time you loop through the items.